# Handle variable path components in Java HttpServer

Tags: java

I'm new in Java. I understand the example in [this site](http://snipplr.com/view/71346/simple-java-http-server-from-java/) and applied it.

What I try to understand is how can I define `/:module/:action` kind of customization where `:module` or `:action` can be anything instead of calling a static url like `/test`

I read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html) but it seems that createContext accepts static string instead of a regex.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
    server.createContext("/test", new MyHandler());
    server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
    server.start();
}
```

Comment: You probably want to build a whole "routing table" with many contexts, one for each module or action.

Comment: If you're new to Java, this might not be the best place to start either.